# CodedUI [testmethod] vs [CodedUITest]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, automation, coded-ui-tests

What is the difference between the [testmethod] and [CodedUITest] tags which begin at the top of each class? I have been unable to find any documentation from Microsoft regarding the contents/behavior of these class declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodedUITest is meta attribute of graphic test, he can be generated from data recordered with Microsoft Test Manager for example

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx

Testmethod : is meta attribute of one method of your test

Link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [CodedUITest] attribute preceeds the class and indicates that the class supplies Coded UI tests. There are other attributes to indicate other types of test class. For example the [TestClass] for unit testing with Visual Studio.

The [TestMethod] attribute preceeds a method in the class and indicates that the method should be executed to perform a test. The TestMethod attribute is commonly used with the [DataSource(...)] attribute to specify data driven tests. The DataSource attribute takes parameters that describe the location and format of data and indicates that the test should be run multiple times using the data provided.

Note that the attribute names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I observed one small difference between [CodedUI] and [TestClass] attributes is,
with [TestClass] we have to call driver.Close() or driver.Quit() methods explicitly to close all the opened browsers but with [CodedUI] all the open browsers get closed automatically/implicitly.